# how can I run a powershell script in a docker-compose.yml command field?

Tags: docker, powershell, docker-compose

I'm new to Docker and I'm following a tutorial that was made for Linux (I'm using Windows). I am trying to change a ./script.sh command with one that uses a PowerShell script. &script.ps1 does not work. Here is the code:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  frontend:
    depends_on: 
      - backend
    build: ./frontend
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    

  backend: 
    depends_on: 
      - db
    build: ./backend
    ports: 
      - 3001:3001
    environment: 
      DB_URL: mongodb://db/vidly
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/app
    command: &script.ps1  # instead of ./script.sh
  db:
    image: mongo:4.0-xenial
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - vidly:/data/db

volumes:
  vidly:
```

the error I receive is
**in ".\docker-compose.yml", line 22, column 14
expected alphabetic or numeric character, but found '"'  in ".\docker-compose.yml", line 22, column 15**

Comment: In entrypoint node I use this :     powershell.exe -Command "& script.ps1"     I am just not 100% sure of it works in command node.

Answer (score 0):

> in ".\docker-compose.yml", line 22, column 14 expected alphabetic or numeric character, but found '"' in ".\docker-compose.yml", line 22, column 15

Every `docker-compose.yaml` first need to be a valid yaml file, you could use `docker-compose config` to verify it. Here, what you need to is wrap `&script.ps1` with double quotation mark to make it be valid yaml:

```
command: "&script.ps1"
```